# C++ Compilation Issue, template argument 2 is invalid

Tags: c++, ros, nvidia-jetson

I have a rather large code base. It is all here https://github.com/mpkuse/nap/tree/master-desktop/src

It is actually a ros package which has to be compiled with `catkin_make`
which is an layer over cmake.

My code base compiles fine on my ubuntu-desktop (gcc version 5.4.0). 
However, as I move it to Nvidia-TX2, I get very long error list. A snippet of it as below. The class Node is defined in Node.h and included in other classes.

```
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:73:68: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:73:68: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:73:68: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:73:56: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::vector’ without an argument list
   LocalBundle( const nap::NapMsg::ConstPtr& msg, const vector<Node*>& global_nodes, const PinholeCamera& camera   );
                                                        ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:73:62: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   LocalBundle( const nap::NapMsg::ConstPtr& msg, const vector<Node*>& global_nodes, const PinholeCamera& camera   );
                                                              ^
In file included from /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:82:0,
                 from /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager_rviz_visualization.cpp:1:
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   int find_indexof_node(  const vector<Node*>& global_nodes, ros::Time stamp );
                                             ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/LocalBundle.h:127:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

What is going on here? Any suggestions?

I tried to isolate the problem. Here is what I did, I completely removed the classes `LocalBundle` and `Corvus`. They were being used in DataManager_core.cpp/place_recog_callback(). Also removed corresponding cmake entries. Now the code can compile.

I tried adding a dummy class `Suse`

```
// Suse.h
#pragma once


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

class Suse
{
public:
  Suse();

  void sayHi();

};
```

;

```
// Suse.cpp 
#include "Suse.h"

Suse::Suse()
{

}


void Suse::sayHi()
{
  cout << "Hi from Suse\n";
}
```

Then tried to use this class in exact same place (ie. in place_recog_callback()) like:

```
  Suse sy = Suse();
  sy.sayHi();
```

Also added Suse.cpp in cmake compile list and included Suse.h in DataManager.h.

With this it compiles successfully.

However, as I include opencv in Suse.h something like:

```
// //opencv
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace cv;
```

I get a long error message, first few lines of which look similar to original error.

```
[ 81%] Building CXX object nap/CMakeFiles/pose_graph_opt_node.dir/src/DataManager_core.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object nap/CMakeFiles/pose_graph_opt_node.dir/src/DataManager_rviz_visualization.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object nap/CMakeFiles/pose_graph_opt_node.dir/src/pose_graph_opt_node.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object nap/CMakeFiles/pose_graph_opt_node.dir/src/DataManager_utils.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object nap/CMakeFiles/pose_graph_opt_node.dir/src/Suse.cpp.o
In file included from /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager_core.cpp:1:0:
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:171:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   const vector<Node*>& getNodesRef() { return nNodes; }
                     ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:171:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:185:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   vector<Node*> nNodes; //list of notes
               ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:185:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
In file included from /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager_rviz_visualization.cpp:1:0:
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:171:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   const vector<Node*>& getNodesRef() { return nNodes; }
                     ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:171:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:185:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   vector<Node*> nNodes; //list of notes
               ^
/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/nap/src/DataManager.h:185:15: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Comment: Is that the first error message?

Comment: yes thats the first error message

Comment: could it be due to #pragma? I am using #pragma once in headers

Comment: The only way this error message makes sense to me is if `Node` were `#define`'d to be something else. But it's hard to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: Just added a minimal example in my description above

Comment: What if you add `#ifdef Node` `#error Node is a macro, WTF` `#endif`?

Comment: Node isn't a preprocessor macro (verified) but cv::Node is defined somewhere I think, which might be causing error.

Comment: @melpomene My issue is fixed. removing `using namespace cv` from the headers fixed the issue. Thanks for the quick tip though. Appreciated! If you write up a short answer I could upvote, accept and close the question.

Comment: It is not a good practice to declare 'using namespace' in the header file, because of the lose of control of its scope.